# Paperclip not saving file in ROR 3.1.1 and Ruby 1.9.2

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip, ruby-1.9.2

I am using Paperclip to upload images, but for some reason paperclip is not saving images in my rails app.

Here is my Controller

```
def create 
@product = Product.new(params[:product])
if @product.save
 # flash[:notice] => "Product successfully added"
  redirect_to product_path @product.id
else
  #flash[:notice] => "Something went wrong"
  render new_product_path
end
end
```

and my Model

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :user, :dependent => :destroy
  #validates :name, :presence => true
  has_attached_file :photo
  # has_one :category

  attr_accessible :name, :description, :from, :photo_file_name, :photo_content_type,    :photo_file_size, :photo_updated_at

 end
```

and View

```
<%= form_for(@product, :html => { :multipart => true }) do |f| %>
<p> <%= f.label :name %><br />
<%= f.text_field :name %></p>
<p> <%= f.label :description %><br />
<%= f.text_area :description, :rows => 4%></p>
<p> <%= f.label :price %><br />
<%= f.text_field :from %></p>
<p><%= f.label :photo%><br />
<%= f.file_field :photo%></p>
```

Migration

```
class AddAttachmentPhotoToProduct < ActiveRecord::Migration
 def self.up
add_column :products, :photo_file_name, :string
add_column :products, :photo_content_type, :string
add_column :products, :photo_file_size, :integer
add_column :products, :photo_updated_at, :datetime
 end

 def self.down
remove_column :products, :photo_file_name
remove_column :products, :photo_content_type
remove_column :products, :photo_file_size
remove_column :products, :photo_updated_at
 end
end
```

When i tried to validate presence of Photo; validation failed. Any help would be appreciated. Also, I want to re-size/reduce size and save resized photo only as I have limited space in database.

Comment: Basic question: Do you have ImageMagick installed and working?

Comment: In view file do you have :html => { :multipart => true } ?

Comment: Yes. <%= form_for(@product, :html => { :multipart => true }) do |f| %>